# pandas lagged value of time series (previous year) for cohort

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, lag, shift

For a dataframe of:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'dt':[
        '2019-01-01',
        '2019-01-02',
        '2019-01-03',
        '2020-01-01',
        '2020-01-02',
        '2020-01-03',
        '2019-01-01',
        '2019-01-02',
        '2019-01-03',
        '2020-01-01',
        '2020-01-02',
        '2020-01-03'
    ],
    'foo': [1,2,3, 4,5,6, 1,5,3, 4,10,6],

    'category': [1,1,1,1,1,1,  2,2,2,2,2,2]
})
```

How can I find the lagged value from the previous year for each category?

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
display(df)
```

Shifting the index only returns an empty result, and thus fails assignment.

```
df['last_year'] = df[df.dt == df.dt - pd.offsets.Day(365)]
```

Obviously, a join with the data from 2019 on the month and day would work - but seem rahter cumbersome. Is there a better way?

### edit

the desired result:

```
dt  foo     category  last_year
2020-01-01  4   1      1
2020-01-02  5   1      2
2020-01-03  6   1      3
2020-01-01  4   2      1
2020-01-02  10  2      5
2020-01-03  6   2      3
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can `merge` df with itself after you `assign` the column dt with the difference you want with `pd.DateOffset`.

```
print (df.merge(df.assign(dt=lambda x: x['dt']+pd.DateOffset(years=1)), 
                on=['dt', 'category'], 
                suffixes=('','_lastYear'), 
                how='left'))
           dt  foo  category  foo_lastYear
0  2019-01-01    1         1           NaN
1  2019-01-02    2         1           NaN
2  2019-01-03    3         1           NaN
3  2020-01-01    4         1           1.0
4  2020-01-02    5         1           2.0
5  2020-01-03    6         1           3.0
6  2019-01-01    1         2           NaN
7  2019-01-02    5         2           NaN
8  2019-01-03    3         2           NaN
9  2020-01-01    4         2           1.0
10 2020-01-02   10         2           5.0
11 2020-01-03    6         2           3.0
```

Comment: well exactly - as outlined in the question a join with last year would be possible - but is there a more native method like rolling?

Comment: @GeorgHeiler you could use a `groupby` and maybe `shift`, but I don't see how you could align with the index after. or you need to create a `map` per group, but I don't think it would be more "obvious" than this method :) or at least I don't see how!

Comment: @GeorgHeiler with a groupby and using the original idea of @anky, you could do `df['last_year'] = df.groupby(['category']).apply(lambda dfg: dfg['dt'].sub(pd.Timedelta('365D')).dt.date.map(dict(zip(dfg['dt'],dfg['foo'])))).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` but I'm not sure about how more efficient it would be?